# Which block represents a WARC-Block-Digest?

Tags: common-crawl, warc, heritrix

At Line 09 below there is this line: `WARC-Block-Digest: sha1:CLODKYDXCHPVOJMJWHJVT3EJJDKI2RTQ`

```
Line 01: WARC/1.0
Line 02: WARC-Type: request
Line 03: WARC-Target-URI: https://climate.nasa.gov/vital-signs/carbon-dioxide/
Line 04: Content-Type: application/http;msgtype=request
Line 05: WARC-Date: 2018-11-03T17:20:02Z
Line 06: WARC-Record-ID: <urn:uuid:e44bc1ea-61a1-4200-b94f-60042456f638>
Line 07: WARC-IP-Address: 54.230.195.16
Line 08: WARC-Warcinfo-ID: <urn:uuid:6d14bf1d-0ef7-4f03-9de2-e578d105d3cb>
Line 09: WARC-Block-Digest: sha1:CLODKYDXCHPVOJMJWHJVT3EJJDKI2RTQ
Line 10: Content-Length: 141
Line 11:
Line 12: GET /vital-signs/carbon-dioxide/ HTTP/1.1
Line 13: User-Agent: Wget/1.15 (linux-gnu)
Line 14: Accept: */*
Line 15: Host: climate.nasa.gov
Line 16: Connection: Keep-Alive
```

WARC's specs say that `The WARC-Block-Digest is an optional parameter indicating the algorithm name and calculated value of a digest applied to the full block of the record.`

I've been trying to figure out what `full block of the record` refers to. Is it line 11 to 16? Or Line 12 to 16? Or Line 1 to 16 (without line 9)? I've tried hashing those possibilities but can't get the sha1 (base 32) value above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A WARC record of a HTTP GET requests has three parts (cf. the [WARC spec](https://iipc.github.io/warc-specifications/specifications/warc-format/warc-1.1/#request)):

1. the WARC header
2. the HTTP request header
3. the payload which is empty (note: a POST requests would include a non-empty payload)

The payload digest of the record is the base32-encoded SHA-1 of the empty string. A proof using Linux command-line tools:

```
$> echo -n "" | openssl dgst -binary -sha1 | base32
3I42H3S6NNFQ2MSVX7XZKYAYSCX5QBYJ
```

A WARC record has the form:

```
warc-record  = header CRLF
               block CRLF CRLF
```

(see [WARC spec: record model](https://iipc.github.io/warc-specifications/specifications/warc-format/warc-1.1/#file-and-record-model))

The "full" block should include everything up to the trailing `\r\n\r\n`. This means lines 11 to 17. Note: also the [HTTP GET request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Client_request) ends with `\r\n\r\n` (a trailing blank line):

```
$> cat request 
GET /vital-signs/carbon-dioxide/ HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Wget/1.15 (linux-gnu)
Accept: */*
Host: climate.nasa.gov
Connection: Keep-Alive

$> tail -n2 request | hexdump -C
00000000  43 6f 6e 6e 65 63 74 69  6f 6e 3a 20 4b 65 65 70  |Connection: Keep|
00000010  2d 41 6c 69 76 65 0d 0a  0d 0a                    |-Alive....|
0000001a
$> cat request | openssl dgst -binary -sha1 | base32
CLODKYDXCHPVOJMJWHJVT3EJJDKI2RTQ
```